# SSMS - Missing heading (Column names) in SQLQuery Grid Results

Tags: sql-server, fonts, configuration, grid, ssms

I have been configuring Fonts and Colors via Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors.

Unfortunately after restarting SSMS to see changes for grid results, a table shows values without column names. I spent many hours to find the option responsible for such behaviour but with no avail.

[image]

When I click on heading to highlight it, there is still no text (column name) being shown.

I will be greatly appreciated for any help to make SQLQuery Grid Results show headings without going to defaut options.

Comment: What "Color" did you use in "Options"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of looking for a solution, the culprit of the problem was **FONT Type** in

- Tools

  - Options

    - Fonts and Colors

      - Grid Results

        - Font

It looks like for **"Cambria Math"** font type, column names in grid results will disapear.